# Error in creating a list with SqlParameter as type

Tags: c#, asp.net

To build a dynamic query I am writing some code like this

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
   sql.Append("SELECT ... all your columns ... FROM yourTable");
   List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>(); 
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paraCategory))
         {
        sql.Append("[Category]=@Category,");
         parameters.AddWithvalue("@Category", paraCategory);
         }
   sql.Length -= 1;
   sql.Append("ORDER BY CreatedDate");
   ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(GlobalSettings.DbDSN, CommandType.Text, sql.ToString(), parameters);
```

Now it throws an error like this

```
Error   1   'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter>' does not contain a definition for 'AddWithvalue' and no extension method 'AddWithvalue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(string, System.Data.CommandType, string, params System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[])' has some invalid arguments   
Error   3   Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter>' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[]'
```

I am not sure what I need to do now..please lend a hand/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error 1:**

You need to add parameters in your list like:

```
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Category", paraCategory));
```

**Error 2 and 3**

It appears that your method `SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset` takes an array as an input for SqlParameters, currently you are passing it as a `List`, just add `.ToArray()` at the end.

```
ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(
                             GlobalSettings.DbDSN, 
                             CommandType.Text, 
                             sql.ToString(), 
                             parameters.ToArray()); //right here
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
parameters.AddWithvalue("@Category", paraCategory);
```

to something like

```
parameters.Add( new SqlParameter("@Category", paraCategory));
```

Answer (score 1):

`AddWithValue` is a method of the [`SqlParameterCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx). No wonder the compiler complains about using it on a  `List<SqlParameter>`.

That being said, be aware that using the out-of-the-box `AddWithValue` is a huge anti-pattern. It results in very serious performance problems in the SQL Server engine. See [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx) for details. for the record, using `new SqlParameter("@name", value)` suffers from exactly the same problems. Read the article.